# Accessing variables outside of anonymous class

Tags: java, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, anonymous-class

I am currently working with IBM's Speech to Text services included in the IBM Watson java SDK. I am trying to set the transcript String to be equal to the results' transcript. However, when I run this code the value is not printed. I am unsure why this is happening, or how to resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated. I have tried using an external setter with a static variable outside the main method, but I was unsuccessful.

```
final String[] transcript = {""};
    service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTranscription(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
            for(int i = 0; i < speechResults.getResults().size(); i++){
                transcript[0] = transcript[0] + speechResults.getResults().get(i).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript() + "\n";
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println(transcript[0]);
```

Comment: That's an asynchronous request. When you call `System.out`, your array might still be empty.

Comment: Did you try to print inside `onTranscription` to verify that transcript[0] is modified?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have tried that and it printed successfully. So it is being modified.

Comment: @CrazySabbath I believe you may be right. I'm going to have to find a solution and try that.

Comment: It looks like you need a boolean flag that you set to true after the for loop in the callback  and then have  your code after the callback waiting for this flag to be set to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your array transcript in a class that has its own handler or consumer ( a way to deal with async requests).

Like so:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class ArrayWrapper {

    private Consumer consumer;

    private Object [] array;

    public ArrayWrapper(int size) {
        this.array = new Object [size];
    }

    public void addConsumer(Consumer consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    public void add(Object o, int index) {
        array[index] = o;
        consumer.accept(o);
    }

    public Object [] get() {
        return array;
    }
}
```

Then you can just implement your logic inside Consumer:

```
ArrayWrapper transcript = new ArrayWrapper(1);
transcript.addConsumer(new Consumer() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Object o) {
        // perform your operations 
        System.out.println(o);
    }
});

service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTranscription(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
        for(int i = 0; i < speechResults.getResults().size(); i++){
            String newTranscript = transcript.get()[0] + speechResults.getResults().get(i).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript() + "\n";
            transcript.add(newTranscript, 0);
        }
    }
});
```

This is just an example, but the idea is that you either have to use a function inside callback, some signal to tell you when loop is done inside callback or something similar.

Edit:

Or you can do this in a simpler way (without any additional classes):

```
    final String[] transcript = {""};
    Consumer<String> consumer = new Consumer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(String s) {
            //your operations
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    };
    service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTranscription(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
            for(int i = 0; i < speechResults.getResults().size(); i++){
                transcript[0] = transcript[0] + speechResults.getResults().get(i).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript() + "\n";
                consumer.accept(transcript[0]);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: As you suggested, this worked for me with a little tweaking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `recognizeUsingWebSocket` is an asynchronous call. So, by the time you do `System.out.println(transcript[0]` the call you made to the IBM Watson service most likely hasn't finished yet.

You will know that the async operation has finished when the callback method `onTranscription` is triggered. Therefore, inside that method and after the `for` loop, you can be sure that the `transcript` array will already have some values in it. There, you can do whatever you want with the result.

If you want to use the transcript value outside of the callback, the simplest solution would be to define a new method in your class and call it at the end of the `onTranscript` callback.

```
...
public void onTranscriptReceived(String[] transcript) {
     // Do whatever you want
}
...

final String[] transcript = {""};
service.recognizeUsingWebSocket(options, new BaseRecognizeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onTranscription(SpeechRecognitionResults speechResults) {
        for(int i = 0; i < speechResults.getResults().size(); i++){
            transcript[0] = transcript[0] + speechResults.getResults().get(i).getAlternatives().get(0).getTranscript() + "\n";
        }
        onTranscriptReceived(transcript);
    }
});
```

There are many other solutions out there to handle async calls. Personally, I like the [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) libraries, in your case [RxJava specifically](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava). It might take some time to learn, but it is definitely worth it.